# Url rewrite not working when there are forward slashes inside the query value

Tags: url, iis, web, url-rewriting, web-config

I have a original URL which looks likes this:

```
https://example.com/?page=map&path=Video's
```

I created a rule within the IIS manager, which rewrites above to

```
http://h2609709.stratoserver.net/map/Video's/
```

This works fine.

---

*However*, when the original URL is like this:

```
https://example.com/?page=map&path=Video's/birthday/2016
```

It gets correctly rewritten to:

```
https://example.com/map/Video's/birthday/2016/
```

But the page results in a error 404. How can I let the server interpret `&path=Video's/birthday/2016` as a *query* value rather than a remote folder path?

The problem is caused by the `/` character inside the query string.

**Web.config**

```
<rule name="RedirectUserFriendlyURL1" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^$" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="^POST$" negate="true" />
    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^page=([^=&amp;]+)&amp;path=([^=&amp;]+)$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}/{C:2}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
<rule name="RewriteUserFriendlyURL1" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="?page={R:1}&amp;path={R:2}" />
</rule>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like that what you need:

```
<rule name="RewriteUserFriendlyURL1" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^([^/]+)/(.*)/?$" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="?page={R:1}&amp;path={R:2}" />
</rule>
```

I changed the regexp. Now `{R:1}` is first word betweeh slashes and `{R:2}` is everything after

Comment: Ok, thanks. Ill try it later today. I get back to you.